# Extract a certificate using a Batch file

Tags: batch-file, https, x509

Is there any way of downloading a https certificate using a batch file (or a powershell script) in Windows? In Linux I can use `openssl s_client -connect <URL> ...`
How can I do it in windows (without using thirdparty openssl implementations)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time ago I wrote a `Test-WebServerSSL` PowerShell script that does the thing: [Test remote web server SSL certificate](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/test-remote-web-server-ssl-certificate.aspx). The function utilizes built-in `System.Net.WebRequest` class and its [ServicePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

just copy/paste the function to your PowerShell console and call it by specifying remote server host name:

```
Test-WebServerSSL www.mydomain.com
```

Note that you must type only remote server's host name without protocol prefix and relative URL path.

to save the certificate to a file, you can send the output object to `Set-Content` cmdlet:

```
$SSL = Test-WebserverSSL www.mydomain.com
Set-Content -Path $CertificateFile -Value $SSL.Certificate.RawData -Encoding Byte
```

Comment: Thanks for this, will check it out!

Comment: Is there a way to save it as I would be able to in openssl using `openssl x509 -outform PEM > foo`